# Mapping chain of calls in Vim involving `execute' command

Tags: vim

Trying to map

```
nmap <silent> <leader>P :echo "something" | execute "!ls"<CR>
```

returns an error:

```
E121: Undefined variable: CR
E15: Invalid expression: "!ls"<CR>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `<bar>` not `|` when mapping commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `<bar>` instead of `|` in mappings.

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>P :echo "something" <bar> execute "!ls"<CR>
```

Note: Should probably be using `nnoremap`